# Question about finding a distribution without taking into account previous events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> We have 8 prisoners, each has a probability of escaping (independently) each day of $0.4$, what is the distribution of the amount of escaping prisoners on the third day?

This is the answer: the probability of one escaping on the third day is $0.6^2\cdot 0.4=0.144$, so let $x$ be the wanted amount and we have $x\sim B(8,0.144)$.

My question is, why we don't take into account the probability of some of the prisoners escaping before the third day? Doesn't this assume all 8 prisoners are still there by the third day?

Comment: Is this verbatim or paraphrased / translated?

Comment: Translated, I'll try to rephrase if something isn't clear @joriki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the factor $0.6^2$ that takes into account the possibility of prisoners escaping before the third day. On each day, the probability of a prisoner escaping is $0.4$, so the probability of the prisoner staying is $0.6$, and this is squared because there are two days before the third day on which the prisoner might escape.

Comment: So because of the $0.6^2$ we can assume that all 8 prisoners didn't escape in the first two days?

Comment: @kuhaku: No, why should we assume that? Some of them might have escaped.

Comment: @kuhaku: The probability of the prisoner escaping on the third day is the product of three independent probabilities: Not escaping on the first day ($0.6$), not escaping on the second day ($0.6$), and escaping on the third day ($0.4$).

Comment: It just look like we assume that there are 8 prisoners on the third day because of the 8 in $x\sim B(8,0.144)$.

Comment: @kuhaku: There's no such assumption. We calculate the probability for each prisoner, taking into account that the prisoner may escape on one of the first two days. This calculation applies to all $8$ prisoners; the probability of escaping on the third day is $0.144$ for all $8$ of them; so the distribution of the number of prisoners escaping on the third day is $B(8,0.144)$. That all $8$ of them have this probability of escaping on the third day in no way implies that they all do, or that none of them escaped earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The probability an individual prisoner escapes on the first day is $0.4$.

The probability an individual prisoner does not escapes on the first day is $0.6$.

The probability an individual prisoner does not escapes on the first day but escapes on the second day is $0.24$.

The probability an individual prisoner does not escapes on the first two days is $0.36$.

The probability an individual prisoner does not escapes on the first two days but escapes on the third day is $0.144$.  This is the only number we are interested in for the next part of the question.

As  a check, the probability an individual prisoner does not escapes on the first three days is $0.216$. You can see $0.4+0.24+0.144+0.216 =1$.  The probability a prisoner either escapes earlier or does not escape is $0.4+0.24+0.216 = 0.856$ and this enters the binomial distribution as $(1-0.144)$.